# Can't apply union with where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a default value **"Choose a Restaurant"** to my query result with these query;

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT No_,Name + ' - ' + No_ Name FROM [dbo].[TestDB]
UNION
SELECT '<Choose a Restaurant>' AS Name) A
WHERE [Alt Grup] = 'TAB' or [Alt Grup] = 'FRC' or [Alt Grup] = 'KIB' or [Alt Grup] = 'ORK')
       and (Blocked = 0)
       and ([Chain Name] = '01-TAB' or [Chain Name] = 'YURT DIŞI' or [Chain Name] = 'FAS')
       and [Show On Web] = 1
       and No_ != '2001.10.01.000998'
ORDER BY Name
```

However, it is not succeed. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is the original query before I edited it in order to implent `Union`;

```
select No_,Name + ' - '+No_ Name, 'Choose a Rest' from [dbo].[TestDB]
where ([Alt Grup] = 'TAB' or [Alt Grup] = 'FRC' or [Alt Grup] = 'KIB' or [Alt Grup] = 'ORK')
       and (Blocked = 0)
       and ([Chain Name] = '01-TAB' or [Chain Name] = 'YURT DIŞI' or [Chain Name] = 'FAS')
       and [Show On Web] = 1
       and No_ != '2001.10.01.000998'
order by Name
```

Comment: Can you share your input and desired output?

Comment: Your where clause is on the wrong query. Also, you are going to run into another issue because your default row will not have the same number of columns. When you post questions about an error it would be HUGELY beneficial to post the error message instead of "it is not succeed".

Comment: `SELECT something as No_, '<Choose a Restaurant>' AS Name`, and you don't have columns in `FROM` for your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @SeanLange, I can't produce the error right now, I am on SQL Reporting Service and I only take the error "syntax is wrong".

Comment: So when that happens take the query and run it in SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with your query. I would restructure this into something more along these lines.

```
SELECT No_
    , Name + ' - ' + No_ Name 
FROM [dbo].[TestDB]
WHERE [Alt Grup] in ('TAB', 'FRC', 'KIB', 'ORK')
    and Blocked = 0
    and [Chain Name] in ('01-TAB', 'YURT DIŞI', 'FAS')
    and [Show On Web] = 1
    and No_ != '2001.10.01.000998'

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL
    , '<Choose a Restaurant>' AS Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Query works but it does not add <Choose a Restaurant> on query result.

Comment: Ummm....yes it does. It is the second query in the union. ;) Maybe you need to switch that with the No_ column? But glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have   a wrong column name sequence  in first select  (seems two column but the 
No_ Name seems wrong)

```
  No_, Name + ' - ' + No_ Name FROM [dbo].[TestDB]
```

for a UNION you need  the same number and corresponding data type column in both the select  so you could try

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
  SELECT 'No_' + Name + ' - ' + No_ + Name AS name
  FROM [dbo].[TestDB] 
  UNION
  SELECT '<Choose a Restaurant>' 
) A

ORDER BY Name
```

and you can use in WHERE clause only column name present in table  ( subquery ()A) 
 you have 
So you could filter only for value of name ..

Comment: This isn't going to work because the columns in the where predicates do no exist in the derived table.